# Pandas join or loop to update an existing column from another table

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to write update a column of my denominator table with merge function. The table are just like this.

```
Table A
A B C D E 
1 2 5 2 a
2 2 5 3 a
3 3 6 4 c
4 4 4 1 c
700rows

Table B
A B C D E 
1 2 5 2 c
2 2 5 3 c
3 3 6 4 c

500rows
```

The first table is the one I got from DB with the fixed number of records I need to serve as the denominator, so the total number of rows can't change, the second table is the one I also pull from another sever with the update information of column E. The row number of table B is less than the row number(fixed) of table A. I just wanna update column E in table A as much as I could get from table B.   I tried all types of join and they will change the row number after updating, do you have any ideas to solve by merge function or any other methods?

The output should be:

```
A B C D E 
1 2 5 2 c
2 2 5 3 c
3 3 6 4 c
4 4 4 1 c
700 rows
```

The row number won't change for table A. But just for column E, it is updated by the same record in table B if existed there.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this is not an R question

Comment: Why r and sql if title says pandas?

Comment: Just wanna have a look at if anyone can also solve in R or I can upload the two tables in SQL to solve in SQL. I am just trying to solve using pandas right now..

Answer (score 1):

In R, I think you can perform `left_join` to keep rows in first dataset unchanged and then select the values from `B` dataset if present or from `A` using `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(A, B, by  = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>%
  mutate(E = coalesce(E.y, E.x)) %>%
  select(-E.x, -E.y)

#  A B C D E
#1 1 2 5 2 c
#2 2 2 5 3 c
#3 3 3 6 4 c
#4 4 4 4 1 c
```

**data**

Assuming `A` and `B` are two datasets.

```
A <- structure(list(A = 1:4, B = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), C = c(5L, 5L, 
6L, 4L), D = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

B <- structure(list(A = 1:3, B = c(2L, 2L, 3L), C = c(5L, 5L, 6L), 
D = 2:4, E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "c", class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the dplyr almost solve 99% of the problem, only add 5 or 6 duplicates which  is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the most elegant way to do that but this code should work on R:

```r
TableA = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4), B = c(2,2,3,4), C = c(5,5,6,4), D = c(2,3,4,1), E = c("a","a","c","c"))
TableB = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4), B = c(2,2,3,4), C = c(5,5,6,4), D = c(2,3,4,1), E = c("c","c","c","c") )
```

Using a `for` loop for testing each row `TableA` versus each row `TableB` and replace column `E` of `TableA` by column `E` of `TableB` if rows are identical (for columns A,B,C,D):

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(TableB))
{
  if(length(grep(FALSE,TableB[i,c(1:4)]==TableA[i,c(1:4)]))==0){TableA[i,"E"] = TableB[i,"E"]}
  else{}
}
```

And the output:

```r
> TableA
  A B C D E
1 1 2 5 2 c
2 2 2 5 3 c
3 3 3 6 4 c
4 4 4 4 1 c
```

Does it answer your question ?